# Strange Ajax / Jquery behaviour in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, jquery

I have an ajax call inside a javascript function that update a div with the result. This function is called every 2 seconds.

```
function RefreshNbrMsg() { 
   $.ajax({ 
      url: 'helper/NewMessages.aspx', 
      success: function (data) { 
         $('#nbr_msg').empty().append(data); 
      } 
   }); 
} 

$(document).ready(function () { 
   setInterval(RefreshNbrMsg, 2000); 
});
```

My problem is that it's working perfectly with Chrome but not IE. In IE the div won't update.

I don't have any script error or messages. I can see in the network analyzer that the ajax call is done every 2 seconds.

/helper/NewMessages.aspx GET 304 text/html 108 B < 1 ms JS Library XMLHttpRequest

Any ideas ?

Comment: The `304` reply indicates caching is taking place. Maybe IE9 doesn't like this. Can you try passing `cache: false` to `$.ajax()` to see if it fixes the problem?

Comment: I didn't know that I'll try to disable cache ! thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
    function RefreshNbrMsg() {
        $.ajax({
           cache: false,
           url: 'helper/NewMessages.aspx',
           success: function (data) 
           {
                $('#nbr_msg').empty().append(data);
           }
        });
    }


    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(RefreshNbrMsg, 2000);
    });
```